# ip2nation - don't understand how the ip value is stored

Tags: mysql, geolocation

The [ip2nation](http://www.ip2nation.com/ip2nation) table stores ip values like such:

```
IP      COUNTRY
687865856   za
689963008   eg
```

How does this translate into an actual IP address block range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, it uses [INET_ATON()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and [INET_NTOA()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) mysql function

update:
Yep. I've just checked.

```
SELECT INET_NTOA( 687865856 )
>> 41.0.0.0
SELECT INET_NTOA( 689963008 )
>> 41.32.0.0
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct. It's stored as an integer that represents the numeric value of the address.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the [Sample Scripts](http://www.ip2nation.com/ip2nation/Sample_Scripts/Output_Full_Country_Name):

```
SELECT 
    c.country 
FROM 
    ip2nationCountries c,
    ip2nation i 
WHERE 
    i.ip < INET_ATON("'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'") 
    AND 
    c.code = i.country 
ORDER BY 
    i.ip DESC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: Odd how it's less-than instead of <= ... direct IP matches at the bottom limit of the range will be incorrect (as I'm finding).